# AWS | How to have CORS allow access from specific domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to lock down inbound calls to my Elastic Beanstalk / EC2 AWS server by specific IP's and domain

Example - Allow access to either:

- IP's: 123.456.789, 234.567.890
- Domain: http://localhost:8080 (From local Angular Web App)

I am using security groups to whitelist the IP's successfully. After reading the AWS docs it seemed [CORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) would be my solution for allowing domain access but I am having issues. The link instructs to write XML into the CORS configuration in the S3 bucket. Mine looks as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:8080</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Here are my EXPECTED/ACTUAL scenario/results:

- If IP not in whitelisted security group BUT domain is within CORS XML: 'http://localhost:8080' - EXPECTED: GET call to return data. ACTUAL: Nothing is returned (Call hangs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to limit an S3 bucket access to specific IP addresses, you need to create a bucket policy with a condition containing the IP addresses. If the IP address you're allowing belong to an EC2, you should create an IAM role, attach it to the EC2(s), and limit the bucket to the role ARN. This provides better security overall, and your EC2 IP address will change if you do not have an elastic IP associated to it and the server goes down for any reason.

An example bucket policy to limit access based on specific IPs [taken from the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3) is as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1",
         "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
         "NotIpAddress": {
            "aws:SourceIp": [
                "123.456.789/32",
                "234.567.890/32"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This denies all access to any IP that does not match the list of IPs given and allows those specific IPs ALL access to the bucket (this is not a good practice).

If you are trying to limit access to the bucket by an EC2 instance, you would want o use something like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "RoleAllow",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/service-role/role-name",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1",
         "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

You'd modify the `Principal` field with the ARN of the Role. You can attach a role to an EC2 from the console by right-clicking the instance, going to `Instance Settings` and then clicking `Attach/Replace IAM Role`.

If you're trying to access the S3 bucket from just YOUR machine, use the first one and substitute your IP address with the list of IPs.

EDIT:
As mentioned in the comments, to restrict S3 access by an HTTP referrer, you can do so with the bucket policy as well.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This example is [pulled directly from the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4).

Comment: Thank you for the help @scrgrk. Would this solution extend to domains as well or just IP's? The IP's I'm whitelisting is the developers machines while the domain would be the hosted site.

Comment: You can use a condition for HTTP referrer in a bucket policy. I'll edit the post with that information.

Comment: Marking this correct because it does block/allow access to the S3 bucket by domain. Will ask another question in new post to clarify on how to allow access by domain to hit server endpoints that do no access S3 buckets.